# jwplayer streaming from yell cdn

Tags: javascript, cdn, jwplayer

Hi have the following code from Yell to stream an mp4 from their cdn via jwplayer.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="> http://cdn.yell.com/player/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="dGV3zHQOXZOcbQ7UUN5GEhKfnU4AWcN+IFtDfg==";</script>
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> jwplayer("myElement").setup({ file: "http://cdn.yell.com/cdn/yellapi/asset/4E13DE4EF6ECD8EA      /mp4.mp4", image: "http://cdn.yell.com/cdn/yellapi/asset/4E13DE4EF6ECD8EA/preview" }); </script>
```

Its not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.yell.com/player/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="dGV3zHQOXZOcbQ7UUN5GEhKfnU4AWcN+IFtDfg==";</script>
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> jwplayer("myElement").setup({ file: "http://cdn.yell.com/cdn/yellapi/asset/4E13DE4EF6ECD8EA/mp4.mp4", image: "http://cdn.yell.com/cdn/yellapi/asset/4E13DE4EF6ECD8EA/preview" }); </script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This code has been forwarded a few times until it got to me, somehow those spaces got in there!?

Comment: No problem! Yeah, the spaces caused the issue.